# Trying to register ExternalInterface.addCallback() in swf

Tags: javascript, flash, externalinterface

I am not a flash developer.  I am trying to wire up communication *from* javascript *to* a .swf file.  I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216446/how-can-i-update-the-text-in-a-loaded-swf-file-with-javascript-as3) and other places that the simplest method was to use `ExternalInterface.addCallback()`.  I have used the above link as well as [the official docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) as reference.

I am pretty sure that I am not trying to call the method in the flash file too early, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302829/as3-externalinterface-addcallback-is-not-working-right).

Here is my HTML (I got this straight from the documentation):

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="Project" width="1024" height="768" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">
    <param name="movie" value="Project.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <embed src="Project.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7" width="1024" height="768" name="Project" align="middle" play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"> </embed>
</object>
```

My Javascript:

```
function sendToActionScript(value) {        
    GetSWF("Project").updateText(value);
}

function GetSWF(strName) {
    if (window.document[strName] != null)
        if (window.document[strName].length == null)
            return window.document[strName];
        else
            return window.document[strName][4];
    else
        if (document[strName].length == null)
            return document[strName];
        else
            return document[strName][5];
}
```

The relevant AS:

```
public function Project_Main() 
{
    commune();
}

public function commune()
{
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("updateText", updateText);
    }
    else
    {
        var displayText:TextTheme = new TextTheme(_ArialBlack, 100, 100, 800, 500, 42);
        addChild(displayText);
        displayText.text = "ERROR:ExternalInterface.NOTavailable";
    }
}

private function updateText(pid:String, playerName:String):void 
{
    var displayText:TextTheme = new TextTheme(_ArialBlack, 100, 100, 800, 500, 42);
    addChild(displayText);
    displayText.text = "PLAYER ID:" + pid + " PLAYER NAME:" + playerName;
}
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1748280/374866) that you cannot have your files hosted from `C:\` so I am hosting the HTML from `http://localhost`.

When I try to call `sendToActionScript("test");` I get this error:

```
Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

It sounds like a permission problem, but as you can see, I have `allowScriptAccess=always`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your 'Project' accessible from JS?

Comment: I assume that you are talking about this --> `GetSWF("Project")`.  The answer is yes.  I am able to 'get' the project.  If I try this : `GetSWF("ProjectWrongName")` then I get 'undefined'.  So it looks like I am able to get the container, just not _do_ anything to it.

Comment: Then maybe the problem is in '''private''' function in A.S.

Comment: and in JS there is 1 parameter, but as a.s. says it sould be two of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in JS there is 1 parameter,

```
GetSWF("Project").updateText(**value**);
```

but as A.S. says it sould be two of them

```
private function updateText(pid:String**, playerName:String**):void
```